# Converting a large pipeline to snakemake

Tags: python, config, snakemake

I have developed MOSCA, a pipeline for meta-omics analysis (MG with MT), which is available through Bioconda. I want to convert it to snakemake, since it would easily allow MOSCA to run simultaneously some accesses through APIs and some computationally demanding tasks. Also, I think it would help better shape the tool to a standard format.

My question is, MOSCA has a lot of parameters, which will have to be transfered to a configuration file. While this is trivial for most parameters, inputting MG and MT files together is trickier. Also, MOSCA considers samples together. So I created a samples' file, `samples.tsv`

```
MG files    MT files    Sample
path/to/mg_R1.fastq,path/to/mg_R2.fastq path/to/mt_R1.fastq,path/to/mt_R2.fastq Sample
```

and I want the Snakefile to read it and retain the "Sample" information. Follows the example for including the MG preprocessing and the assembly of the pipeline, where the `preprocess.py` and `assembly.py` scripts contain the corresponding functionalities.
This is the `Snakefile`

```
from pandas import read_table

configfile: "config.json"

rule all:
  input:
    expand("{output}/Assembly/{experiment[1][Sample]}/contigs.fasta", 
            output = config["output"], experiment = read_table(config["experiments"], "\t").iterrows())

rule mg_preprocess:             # mt_preprocess make same, but data = mrna?
  input:
    list(expand({experiment}[1]["MG files"], experiment = read_table(config["experiments"], "\t").iterrows()))[0]
  output:
    expand("{output}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{name}{fr}_paired.fq", 
            fr = ['forward', 'reverse'], output = config["output"], name = 'pretty_commune')
  threads: 
    config["threads"]
  run:
    shell("""python preprocess.py -i {reads} -t {threads} -o {output} 
            -adaptdir MOSCA/Databases/illumina_adapters -rrnadbs MOSCA/Databases/rRNA_databases""", 
            output = config["output"])

rule assembly:
  input:
    expand("{output}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{name}{fr}_paired.fq", 
            fr = ['forward', 'reverse'], output = config["output"], name = 'pretty_commune')
  output:
    expand("{output}/Assembly/{experiment[1][Sample]}/contigs.fasta", 
            output = config["output"], experiment = read_table(config["experiments"], "\t").iterrows())
  threads:
    config["threads"]
  run:
    reads = ",".join(map(str, input))
    shell("python assembly.py -r {input} -t {threads} -o {output}/Assembly/{sample} -a {assembler}", 
    output = config["output"], sample = config["experiments"][1]["sample"], 
    assembler = config["assembler"])
```

and this is the `config.json`

```
{
"output": 
    "snakemake_learn",
"threads":
    14,
"experiments":
    "samples.tsv",
"assembler":
    "metaspades"
    }
```

and I get the error

```
NameError in line 12 of /path/to/Snakefile:
name 'experiment' is not defined
  File "/path/to/Snakefile", line 12, in <module>
```

How is experiment not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but to me the line

```
list(expand({experiment}[1]["MG files"], experiment = read_table(config["experiments"], "\t").iterrows()))[0]
```

seems too complicated. I would put the sample sheet in a DataFrame and work with that rather using the iterator from `read_table` every time. E.g.:

```
import pandas

ss = pandas.read_csv(config["experiments"], sep= '\t')

...

rule mg_preprocess:             # mt_preprocess make same, but data = mrna?
    input:
        expand('{experiment}', experiment= ss["MG files"][0]),
```

Anyway, I think the error `name 'experiment' is not defined` is because `{experiment}` in `list(expand({experiment}[1]["MG files"]` is not in a string that can be replace with the actual value.

---

EDIT:

In fact the line `expand('{experiment}', experiment= ss["MG files"][0]),` doesn't make a lot of sense... It's just the same as `ss["MG files"][0]`

Comment: I cannot iterate over a pandas DF as is costumary in snakemake. A specific line in a pandas requires to run ```df.loc[index]```, how can I do that in snakemake, for example to say that I want the contigs named ```"{output}/Assembly/{sample_name}/contigs.fasta"```? This
```rule all:
  input:
    expand("{output}/Assembly/{experiment[1][Sample]}/contigs.fasta", 
            output = config["output"], experiment = experiments)```
gives me
```TypeError in line 10 of /path/to/Snakefile:
string indices must be integers
  File "/path/to/Snakefile", line 10, in <module>```

Comment: @JoãoSequeira Snakemake is based on Python. Anything that works in Python works in Snakemake. Try printing experiments. Then try to print the first thing that comes out, then take the second index [1], print that. Then try to take [Sample] from it. Somewhere in this process something goes wrong and we can not know what that is from our computer unfortunately...

Comment: Thank you very much, @Maarten-vd-Sande , I really wanted a way to test this! Now I can see what the problem might be. The first thing that comes out is the first column name, followed by the other column names: ```for i in experiments: print(i) >>col1; >>col2 >>Sample```. Taking the second index of these would make no sense, obviously. To iterate by the rows, I can transpose the df. However, then the values obtained by iterating the df will be the rownames! Can I use these to obtain the informatino for each row in snakemake?

Comment: probably you want to read the table with an `index_col` and `header`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html. To iterate over rows you can then use: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html

Comment: Makes sense, that way I can access each "Sample" of each row, with for example: ```exps = experiments.iterrows(); next(exps)[1]["Sample"]```. But when I want to put that value in, I cannot do ```rule all:
  input:
    expand("{output}/Assembly/{sample[1]["Sample"]}/contigs.fasta", 
            output = config["output"], sample = experiments.iterrows())``` because it brakes the string formatting. Should I do something like this ```{}/Assembly/{}/contigs.fasta.format(config["output"], sample = experiments.iterrows()```, but in a way it works?

Comment: My man @Maarten-vd-Sande thank you very much. I managed to put it to work by simply realising that snakemake reads the columns iteratively, one must only shape the columns as he wants before the iteration. A simple ```rule all:
  input:
    expand("{output}/Assembly/{sample}/contigs.fasta", 
            output = config["output"], sample = experiments["Sample"])``` works, and the same follows for the other rules. Thank you very much, @Maarten-vd-Sande and @dariober